# Android Custom Font Error

Tags: android

I am working out to change the font of TextView using an external font(ttf).
But I got the problem that the layout of my textbox has been shifted down:

[before changing font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFp04.jpg)

[after changing font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXrOa.jpg)

the code I using:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Mr Sunshine 2.ttf");
textview.setTypeface(tf);
```

and my XML Code :

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:background="@drawable/yellowbox"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:id="@+id/textbox"
android:gravity="center"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

I can't figure out what is the error.  Can someone help me?

Comment: your textView xml layout?

Comment: What's the problem? It looks like the font was changed...

Comment: Layout of my textbox has been shifted down

Comment: Mr Sunshine 2.ttf   change to MrSunshine2.ttf

Comment: let me know your result

Comment: There might be some problems with your custom typeface. e.g The baseline of the font is wrong.

Comment: apply the font for all views and check. I saw you just applied for two views. Look like its alignment problem.